# Should I cache or not my unified dataframes?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, caching

I am not familiar with caching in Spark.

I need to do multiple DF unions inside a loop. each union adds few million lines. Should I df.cache my result after each union?

```
var DB_List = List ("Database1", "Database2", "Database3", "Database4", "Database5", "Database6", "Database7", "Database8", "Database9", "Database10")
var df = getDF(spark, DB_List(0)) // this returns a DF.
for(i <- 1 until DB_List.length){    
    df = df.union(getDF(spark, DB_List(i))) 
    //df.cache or not?  
}
//Here, I use df.repartition(1) to write resulted DF in a CSV file.
```

Comment: In this case, you do not need `cache` since you are not reusing the same **df**. However, I am more concerned about the `repatriation(1)` that would blow the memory of the _executor_ if the resulting **df** is too big. - Finally, the name of that variable is not _"ok"_ according to the Scala Style Guide. Finally, you do not need that `var` and that inefficient loop. Just `dbList.map(db => getDF(spark, db)).reduce(_ union _)` or if the list may be empty `dbList.foldLeft(DataFrame.empty) { (df, db) => df union getDF(spark, db) }`.

Comment: Thank you! replacing loop by map reduced significantly execution time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to cache the intermediate result but only the final one.
instead of for loop you can use fold:

```
val dfs = DB_List.map(getDF(spark, _))
val result = dfs.reduce(_ union _)
```